Why my One2many field gives me an error after upgrading the module and the error disappears when restarting the server?
I have a one2many field that gives me this error: AttributeError: '_unknown' object has no attribute 'id' when I try to create a new record, after restart the server the error disapears and only appears again when I update the module , if I restart the server again it disappears again, as far as I can tell it is not a dependencies problem because I use custom models, I will provide the fields I use.
Model:  res.partner.brand
discount_ids = fields.One2many("res.partner.brand.discount", "partner_brand_id", string = "Descuentos marca/proveedor", copy=True)

Model: res.partner.brand.discount
partner_brand_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner.brand', string = "Proveedor marca")
brand_id = fields.Many2one('product.brand', string = "Marca", related="partner_brand_id.brand_id",   readonly=True)
discount_id = fields.Many2one('discount', string = "Descuento")

This is the full error code:
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 368, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 357, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 921, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 546, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1324, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1316, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 469, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 456, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 6525, in onchange
    result['value'] = snapshot1.diff(snapshot0, force=first_call)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 6349, in diff
    result[name] = field.convert_to_onchange(self[name], record, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 2853, in convert_to_onchange
    return super().convert_to_onchange(value._origin, record, names)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 889, in convert_to_onchange
    return self.convert_to_read(value, record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 2829, in convert_to_read
    return value.id
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 654, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
AttributeError: '_unknown' object has no attribute 'id'

I tried the basics, looking in dependencies, using auto_join, making sure I had the right names of the models.
Thanks for your time.

Check the models names and that all models files have been imported

I think the models are correct because when I restart the server everithing works, maybe the files only get all imported after restarting but honestly I dont know hto to look that

When you use related attribute in Odoo, you do not need to declare comodel_name.
Example code:
brand_id = fields.Many2one('product.brand', string = "Marca", related="partner_brand_id.brand_id",   readonly=True) 

=> 

brand_id = fields.Many2one(related="partner_brand_id.brand_id", string = "Marca", readonly=True) 


I changed it, but the error is still there
